# Location of pfSense menu (startup script)?

Tags: pfsense

When pfSense is boot, the following menu is displayed on the screen.

[image]

When we select option number 8 (shell), how do we get back to the menu?

What is the filename for this menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply exit the shell with `exit`

The menu from your screenshot is the default shell for the admin user, `/etc/rc.initial`

Answer (score 2):

i dont have a pfsense for check that but in the github repo its stored at /etc/rc.initial

https://github.com/pfsense/pfsense/blob/be228fd8f726e047564350149a658d25cd008b98/src/etc/rc.initial